# Deque all styles, scripts and plugins to show only post_content html

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin to generate webstories and return the code to be shown using AMP HTML.

The 'post_content' for those pages are already complete with all the tags and the page is ready to be rendered. So I can't have any of the wordpress hooks inserted on those pages.

For some reason I'm not being able to stop Elementor from inserting the heading and footer on those pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have sold the problem with the following code:

```
// Return only post_content when accessing page
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'return_post_content' );
    function return_post_content() {
        // Check if is singular and if post type is ws-auto-generated, if not return
        if ( ! is_singular( 'ws-auto-generated' ) ) {
            return;
        } else {
            global $post;
            $post_content = $post->post_content;
            echo $post_content;
            exit;
        }
    }
```